# jQuery to validate input field for empty characters at end of string?

Tags: jquery, validation

My WordPress theme has a slot for the site owner to input their Adsense Client ID. Apparently its very easy for the user to accidentally grab some empty spaces at the end of the ID during the copy/paste routine.

When this happens, the ads don't work since the Pub ID looks something like this in markup:

```
google_ad_client = "pub-1234567890987654";
```

I'd like to use jQuery to check this value, once its been entered, for empty spaces at the end and alert the user.

Does jQuery have a means to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just trim it using [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

```
google_ad_client = $.trim('pub-1234567890987654    ');
```

Comment: +1 Thanks John, I'm going with trim. Having some issues getting it tied to an event, but that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
$.trim(google_ad_client);
```